# Issue with expo ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync(): Possible unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to create a button in react native, that on being pressed opens the camera and allows the user to take a picture.

For this, I am using the expo image picker.

Here is my code:

```
import { View, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import { useCameraPermissions, PermissionStatus, launchCameraAsync } from 'expo-image-picker';

const ImagePicker = () => {
  const [cameraPermissionInformation, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();

  const verifyPermissions = async () => {
    if (cameraPermissionInformation.status === PermissionStatus.UNDETERMINED) {
      const permissionResponse = await requestPermission();

      return permissionResponse.granted;
    };

    if (cameraPermissionInformation.status === PermissionStatus.DENIED) {
      Alert.alert(
        'Insufficient Permissions',
        'You need to grant camera permissions to use this app.'
      );
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  const takeImageHandler = async () => {
    const hasPermission = await verifyPermissions();

    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }

    const image = await launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [16, 9],
      // quality: 0.5,
    });
    console.log(image);
  };

  

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {/*Additional content to be added here*/}
      </View>
      <Button
        title="Take Image"
        onPress={takeImageHandler}
      />
    </View>
  )
};

export default ImagePicker;
```

When I run the app however, I receive this warning:

[image: error]